# tikz uml, classes with only methods or data members

Tags: tikz-uml

From the tikz uml documentation I have this example.

[image]

If I used the `umlsimpleclass` the two rectangles below the class name wouldn't have be drawn. My question is... is there a way to have only the sections for data members or the sections for methods? It doesn't seem the documentation provides anything.

Update: the full view would be

[image]

For data members the syntax is `visibility_attribute name : type`, while the syntax for method is `visibility_atribute name([name : type,
 name : type, ... ]) : return_type` . That's the difference, what I want to achieve is removing one of the two sections, and keeping just one. Instead of doing both them or none of them.

Something like the "ParentClass" of the diagram below it's what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Some working code to hack:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=3em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass{namespace::A} {
 + n : uint \\ \umlstatic{-- i : int} \\
    \# r : const float} {
    + setA(i : int) : void \\ \umlvirt{\# getA() : A}
}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For those of us not familiar with UML: what are the data members, what are the methods? (In other words, can you explain what you want to change about the graphic without using any UML-lingo?)

Comment: I hope I clarified.

Comment: Not really, that was basically *all* UML-lingo ... I meant in relation to the diagram. Are you asking about how to remove one of the two lower rectangles? Ideally, post the code you have (as code, not as a screenshot), show the output of that code, and describe what you want change about the presentation. Perhaps make a mockup in Paint or similar showing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Shall I show the picture basically of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That would help, yes, as I have no idea what that is. But please post the code as well (a complete example, while you're at it).

Comment: I don't actually see the problem with the UML-lingo anyway... given you have a tag "tikz-uml" I assumed people know what I'm talking about...

Comment: Sure, *some* people here might have understood you perfectly.  I on the other hand know quite a bit TikZ, but zero about UML-stuff. So while I might be perfectly able to answer your question, that doesn't help if I don't understand what you mean. This is why I think it's always helpful to explain what you want to do in terms of the diagram itself, not in terms of the theory of what it represents.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: For the non-uml-speaker amongst us: Can your question be summarised with "draw one of the yellow boxes with only two rows"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as I understand it, you want something like the following, *without* the bottom, empty rectangle.

[image: output of first code block]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass{foo}{bar}{}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At the heart of it, this is just a construct like

```
\node [
   fill=\tikzumlNoteDefaultFillColor,
   draw,
   rectangle split,
   rectangle split parts=3,
   every one node part/.style={font=\bfseries}
   ] {\nodepart{one} foo \nodepart{two} bar \nodepart{three} };
```

which looks like

[image: what the above \node looks like]

The quickest workaround is therefore actually this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2]{foo}{bar}{}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code]

---

Another approach is to make a new macro based on `\umlclass`, where `rectangle split parts` is set to `2`, and the third `\nodepart` is removed. `tikz-uml` does a lot of stuff though. In the `\umlfoobar` macro defined below I've just done as little changes as possible. It works for the given example, but I don't know if there are cases where it might break.

[image: output of last code blocl]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzset{tikzuml foobar style/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split part align={center, left, left}, minimum height=2em, node distance=2em}}

\makeatletter
%
\newcommand{\umlfoobar}[3][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd, x/.initial=\tikzumlDefaultX, y/.initial=\tikzumlDefaultX, width/.initial=\tikzumlClassDefaultWidth, type/.initial=\tikzumlClassDefaultType,%
                               tags/.initial={}, style/.style={},%
                               template/.initial={}, name/.initial=tikzumlEmpty,%
                               draw/.initial=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor,%
                               fill template/.initial=\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorDefaultFillColor,%
                               fill/.initial=\tikzumlClassDefaultFillColor,%
                               text/.initial=\tikzumlDefaultTextColor,%
                               simple/.is if=tikzumlclassSimpleStyle, circle/.is if=tikzumlclassCircleShape, no coords/.is if=tikzumlclassWithoutCoords,%
                               simple=false, circle=false, no coords=false,%
                               .unknown/.code={%
                                 \let\keyname=\pgfkeyscurrentname%
                                 \let\keyvalue=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue%
                                 \ifthenelse{\equal{\keyname}{above}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{left}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{below}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{right}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{above left}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{above right}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{below left}\OR%
                                             \equal{\keyname}{below right}}{%
                                   \IfSubStr{\keyvalue}{ of }{%
                                     \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd, no coords}%
                                   }{}%
                                 }{}%
                                 \ifx\keyvalue\pgfkeysnovalue%
                                   \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd, style/.append style/.expand once={\keyname}}%
                                 \else%
                                   \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd, style/.append style/.expand twice={\expandafter\keyname\expandafter=\keyvalue}}%
                                 \fi%
                                 %\errmessage{TIKZUML ERROR : in umlclass, invalid option \keyname}%
                               }%
  }%
  \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd,#1}%
  %
  \iftikzumlclassSimpleStyle%
    \iftikzumlclassCircleShape%
      \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd, width/.initial=\tikzumlSimpleInterfaceDefaultWidth}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  %
  \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/class/.cd, x/.get=\tikzumlClassX, y/.get=\tikzumlClassY, width/.get=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth,% 
                               type/.get=\tikzumlClassTypeTmp, tags/.get=\tikzumlClassTagsTmp, template/.get=\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorParam,%
                               name/.get=\tikzumlClassName,%
                               draw/.get=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill/.get=\tikzumlClassFillColor,%
                               text/.get=\tikzumlClassTextColor, fill template/.get=\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColor%
  }%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTypeTmp}{class}\OR\equal{\tikzumlClassTypeTmp}{abstract}}{%
    \def\tikzumlClassType{}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikzumlClassType\expandafter{$\ll$\tikzumlClassTypeTmp$\gg$ \\}%
  }%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTagsTmp}{}}{%
    \def\tikzumlClassTags{}%
  }{%
    \def\tikzumlClassTags{\\ \{\tikzumlClassTagsTmp\}}%
  }%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorParam}{}}{%
    \def\tikzumlClassVPadding{}%
    \def\tikzumlClassHPadding{}%
  }{%
    \def\tikzumlClassVPadding{\vspace{0.1em} \\}%
    \def\tikzumlClassHPadding{\hspace{0.5ex} $ $}%
  }%
  %
  \def\tikzumlClassName{#2}%
  %
  \begingroup%
    \def\_{_}\edef\x{\endgroup%
      \def\noexpand\tikzumlClassNodeName{\tikzumlClassName}}\x%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassName}{tikzumlEmpty}}{}{%
    \def\tikzumlClassNodeName{\tikzumlClassName}%
  }%
  %
  \StrSubstitute{\tikzumlClassNodeName}{:}{@COLON@}[\tikzumlClassNodeName]%
  \StrSubstitute{\tikzumlClassNodeName}{\_}{@UNDERSCORE@}[\tikzumlClassNodeName]%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTypeTmp}{abstract}}{%
    \let\tikzumlClassNameOld\tikzumlClassName%
    \def\tikzumlClassName{{\it \tikzumlClassNameOld}}%
  }{}%
  %
  \def\tikzumlClassPos{\tikzumlClassX,\tikzumlClassY}%
  \def\tikzumlClassAttributes{#3}%
%  \def\tikzumlClassOperations{}%
  %
  \iftikzumlclassSimpleStyle%
    \iftikzumlclassWithoutCoords%
      \iftikzumlclassCircleShape%
        \node[tikzuml simpleinterface style, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, minimum width=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth, /tikzuml/class/style] (\tikzumlClassNodeName) {};%
        \node[anchor=south] (\tikzumlClassNodeName-label) at (\tikzumlClassNodeName.north) {\begin{tabular}{c}\tikzumlClassVPadding \tikzumlClassType \tikzumlClassHPadding \textbf{\tikzumlClassName} \tikzumlClassHPadding \tikzumlClassTags \end{tabular}%
        };%
      \else%
        \node[tikzuml simpleclass style, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, minimum width=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth, /tikzuml/class/style] (\tikzumlClassNodeName) {\begin{tabular}{c}\tikzumlClassVPadding \tikzumlClassType \tikzumlClassHPadding \textbf{\tikzumlClassName} \tikzumlClassHPadding \tikzumlClassTags \end{tabular}%
        };%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \iftikzumlclassCircleShape%
        \node[tikzuml simpleinterface style, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, minimum width=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth, /tikzuml/class/style] (\tikzumlClassNodeName) at (\tikzumlClassPos) {};
        \node[anchor=south] (\tikzumlClassNodeName-label) at (\tikzumlClassNodeName.north){\begin{tabular}{c}\tikzumlClassVPadding \tikzumlClassType \tikzumlClassHPadding \textbf{\tikzumlClassName} \tikzumlClassHPadding \tikzumlClassTags \end{tabular}%
        };%
      \else%
        \node[tikzuml simpleclass style, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, minimum width=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth, /tikzuml/class/style] (\tikzumlClassNodeName) at (\tikzumlClassPos) {\begin{tabular}{c}\tikzumlClassVPadding \tikzumlClassType \tikzumlClassHPadding \textbf{\tikzumlClassName} \tikzumlClassHPadding \tikzumlClassTags \end{tabular}%
        };%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \iftikzumlclassWithoutCoords%
      \node[tikzuml foobar style, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, minimum width=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth, /tikzuml/class/style] (\tikzumlClassNodeName) {\begin{tabular}{c}\tikzumlClassVPadding \tikzumlClassType \tikzumlClassHPadding \textbf{\tikzumlClassName} \tikzumlClassHPadding \tikzumlClassTags \end{tabular}%
      \nodepart{second}%
      \begin{tabular}{l}%
      \tikzumlClassAttributes%
      \end{tabular}%
      };%
    \else%
      \node[tikzuml foobar style, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, minimum width=\tikzumlClassMinimumWidth, /tikzuml/class/style] (\tikzumlClassNodeName) at (\tikzumlClassPos) {\begin{tabular}{c}\tikzumlClassVPadding \tikzumlClassType \tikzumlClassHPadding \textbf{\tikzumlClassName} \tikzumlClassHPadding \tikzumlClassTags \end{tabular}%
      \nodepart{second}%
      \begin{tabular}{l}%
      \tikzumlClassAttributes%
      \end{tabular}%
      };%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorParam}{}}{}{%
    \draw (\tikzumlClassNodeName.north east) node[tikzuml template style, name=\tikzumlClassNodeName-template, draw=\tikzumlClassDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColor, text=\tikzumlClassTextColor, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont] {\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorParam};%
  }%
  %
  % add to fit
  \ifnum\c@tikzumlPackageLevel>0%
    \edef\tikzumlPackageFitOld{\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent @@\tikzumlPackage@fitname\endcsname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorParam}{}}{%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent @@\tikzumlPackage@fitname\endcsname{\tikzumlPackageFitOld (\tikzumlClassNodeName)}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent @@\tikzumlPackage@fitname\endcsname{\tikzumlPackageFitOld (\tikzumlClassNodeName) (\tikzumlClassNodeName-template)}%
    }%
    \stepcounter{tikzumlPackageClassNum}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\c@tikzumlComponentLevel>0%
    \def\tikzumlComponentFitTmp{\csname tikzumlComponentFit\tikzumlComponent@parent @@\tikzumlComponent@fitname\endcsname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTemplateFillColorParam}{}}{%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlComponentFit\tikzumlComponent@parent @@\tikzumlComponent@fitname\endcsname{\tikzumlComponentFitTmp (\tikzumlClassNodeName)}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlComponentFit\tikzumlComponent@parent @@\tikzumlComponent@fitname\endcsname{\tikzumlComponentFitTmp (\tikzumlClassNodeName) (\tikzumlClassNodeName-template)}%
    }%
    \stepcounter{tikzumlComponentSubComponentNum}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlfoobar{foo}{bar}
\umlfoobar[x=4]{foo2}{bar}
\umlclass[x=2,y=-2]{foo}{bar}{baz}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So basically I have to create a new command for that, is that right? how do I keep the properties I described above? you kept the rectangle, which is fine, but of course I'd like to keep their meaning as well.

Comment: @user8469759 How is the meaning communicated in the diagram? What is it you need to keep? Both the second and third mandatory argument to `\umlclass` (called respectively "attributes" and "operation" in the code) is handled *exactly* the same way: saved in a macro with e.g. `\def\tikzumlClassAttributes{#3}`, and that macro is later used inside a `tabular` (`\begin{tabular}{l} \tikzumlClassAttributes  \end{tabular}`) which is placed inside a TikZ node.

Comment: @user8469759 Of course you can choose to rename macros so that they are semantically correct.

Comment: by meaning I meant attributes with identifiers etc, or methods with identifiers etc (in terms of the syntax I exposed above).

Comment: @user8469759 I still don't understand how that is supposed to be reflected in the code, apart from perhaps the inputs to the macro.

Comment: Could you kindly add the code that realizes the class `namespace::a` in my original post without the method section for example?

Comment: @user8469759 I don't get it, isn't  that precisely what I've done? And you still haven't said in plain English what the methods section is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64944/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-user8469759).